# What were the first words of the 12 astronauts who stepped on the moon?

Tags: apollo-program, history

@PearsonArtPhoto has thoughtfully assembled a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OJ_iDYAhco) of the words of each of the 12 Apollo astronauts when they stepped on the moon.  In written text, what were they?

Comment: This is very close to a "do my homework for me" question.

Comment: @Hobbes: PearsonArtPhoto did the actual work.  Should he write an answer, he will earn the reputation from it.  Do you want me to write the answer instead?  I don't feel it's ethical for me to take credit for his work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are the first words of the 12 astronauts when they physically **step** on the moon. **Not** when they are descending on the ladder or on the footpad.

### Apollo 11

**Neil Armstrong, CDR:** "That's one small step for [a] man; one giant leap for mankind."

**Edwin "Buzz" Aldrin, LMP:** " Looks like the secondary strut had a little thermal effects on it right here, Neil."

### Apollo 12

**Charles "Pete" Conrad, CDR:** "Mark. Oooh, is that soft and queasy. Hey, that's neat. I don't sink in too far."

**Alan Bean, LMP:** "Okay. My, that Sun is bright."

### Apollo 14

**Alan Shepard, CDR:** "Okay, you're right. Al is on the surface. And it's been a long way, but we're here."

**Edgar "Ed" Mitchell, LMP:** ""He's releasing it now. [This is in reference to Shepard releasing the MET.]""

### Apollo 15

**David Scott, CDR:** "Okay, Houston. As I stand out here in the wonders of the unknown at Hadley, I sort of realize there's a fundamental truth to our nature. Man must explore."

**James "Jim" Irwin, LMP:** "Boy, that front pad is really loose, isn't it? [Reference to him almost falling off the ladder as he took a big jump down]"

### Apollo 16

**John Young, CDR:** "There you are: Mysterious and Unknown Descartes. Highland plains. Apollo 16 is gonna change your image. I'm sure glad they got ol' Brer Rabbit, here, back in the briar patch where he belongs."

**Charles "Charlie" Duke, LMP:** "Fantastic! Oh, that first foot on the lunar surface is super, Tony!"

### Apollo 17

**Eugene "Gene" Cernan, CDR:** "Jack, I'm out here. Oh, my golly! Unbelievable! Unbelievable; but is it bright in the Sun. Okay! We landed in a very shallow depression. That's why we've got a slight pitch-up angle...very shallow, dinner-plate-like, dish crater just about the width of the struts. How you doing, Jack?"

**Harrison "Jack" Schmitt, LMP:** "Hey, who's been tracking up my lunar surface?"

[Source](https://www.alternatewars.com/SpaceRace/First_Words_Moon.htm).

Comment: The moral of the story is: plan your first words carefully or we might have wound up with "Oooh, is that soft and queasy."